# How to code storing uncompressed files from the iPhone's camera?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, camera, avfoundation

The need is to capture an image in an uncompressed format, and save it in a lossless file format. I am not particular about which uncompressed format. However AVCapturePhotoOutput.availablePhotoPixelFormatTypes shows that on my iPhone 14 Pro the BGRA format is available, and its type value is: 1111970369. So I use this code to get a settings object, and trigger a photo capture with it:

```
let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [ String( kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey ) : 1111970369] )
self.photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self )
```

I am not sure I have the AVCapturePhotoSettings() dictionary argument right. It is the best I could conclude from available documentation, and it does not produce a compile time error. I found no example how to do uncompress photo files, I found only one that produces jpegs, and I have successfully used that example to capture images in jpeg format. This is the URL for that example which I now attempt to modify to produce uncompressed image files: https://www.appcoda.com/avfoundation-swift-guide/ . This example is somewhat out of date, and some method names had to be changed accordingly.

Next, when the system calls the delegated callback:

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?)
```

I need to convert the passed photo.pixelBuffer image object into one I can pass to:

```
self.photoCaptureCompletionBlock?(image, nil)
```

UIImage(data: data) çannot do this alone. I get a compile time error when I pass photo.pixelBuffer to it. I tried to convert with the AVCapturePhotoOutput() class, but could not a find version of its initiators the compiler would accept to do this.

What do I need to do to get the data in photo.pixelBuffer stored in an uncompressed file?